# Customize print() page for Form

Tags: html, forms, printing

I was volun-told to recreate captivate projects for work and the one I'm working on now requires some coding. I know a little to get me started, but not enough to make it look like the original project I'm supposed to be recreating. I worked with the head or our gaming department and a professional web developer, but they have been out of touch the past few days and the deadline has come and gone for this.

I would like to add a header and links to the print out page when a user clicks on the print button for a basic html form. Does anyone know how to add this?

I would really appreciate the help since I don't have the skills or the time to properly learn. I've been working through a coding course, but that's weeks from ending.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<textarea id="notes" class="textAreas" rows="30" cols="45" placeholder="Case Notes &#10;&#10;Type anywhere in this space to take notes throughout your conversation with your client. &#10;&#10;After your last case for the day, you'll be able to save your notes to discuss at the meeting with your supervisor."></textarea>
<button id="print">Print</button>
<script> 
  var textArea = document.getElementById('notes');
  var button = document.getElementById('print');
  button.onclick = openPrint;
  function openPrint() {
    var w = window.open();
    w.document.body.innerText = textArea.value;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey welcome! it is a good starting point to share your code and show us what you already did and why you need the help. A question like this, looks like you want someone else to do your homework. I invite you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @javidazac Not homework, just need help with a work task I'm not qualified to do. I'm trying to learn, but it takes much longer to learn than I'm allowed to use on this project. Just looking for help.

Comment: Do you have an image of how it is supposed to look or behave? Only 1 textarea or are there any more inputs?

Comment: @javidazac Here is the link to a video of the original project. https://youtu.be/Lj58g21qFsw?t=66 There is only one text area and the print button is now in the web object window, but when the print button is clicked I need to see the header and the links.